# Validate GPX file when uploading

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xsd

I'm trying to find an effective way to verify when a user uploads a GPX file that it's valid and contains valid content (if possible).

I'll use C# ASP Net uploadFile control so I can validate the file extension but what would be the appropriate way to validate the contents?

From what I've read I can try and use XML/XSD but that's a bit risky as the schema may need updating every so often or it might not work with certain valid GPX files.

Is there a better and effective way to achieve this?